# Generalised theta series for fixed-rank sublattices

Tags: analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, theta-series

The theta series for a lattice $\Lambda$ is defined by
$$\displaystyle \Theta_\Lambda(q) = \sum_{x \in \Lambda} q^{x \cdot x}.$$
Setting $q=e^{-\pi\tau}$ yields the (maybe more usual) related theta series
$$\displaystyle \theta_\Lambda(\tau) = \sum_{x \in \Lambda} e^{-\tau\pi\|x\|^2}.$$
By Poisson formula one gets the functional equation fulfilled by $\theta$: $\theta_\Lambda(\tau) = \frac{1}{\tau^{n/2}\textrm{det}(\Lambda)}\theta_{\Lambda^\lor}\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)$.
It allows to derive some decay information on $\theta_\Lambda$ such as:
$\theta_\Lambda(\tau)\leq \tau^{-n/2}\theta_\Lambda(1)$.

If we want to generalise the definition of the theta series to sublattices (instead of only vectors) we could think of something like:
$$\displaystyle \theta^{(r)}_\Lambda(\tau) = \sum_{\begin{aligned}\ell~ \textrm{su}&\textrm{blattice of}~\Lambda\\ &\textrm{rk}(\ell) = r\end{aligned}} e^{-\tau\pi\cdot\textrm{det}(\ell)^2}, $$
for a fixed integer $1\leq r\leq \textrm{rk}(\Lambda)$. 
One could also restrict the latter sum to only primitive sublattices.

However since the set of sub-lattices of fixed rank is not a lattice itself (it is only embedded in the r-exterior power lattice constructed from $\Lambda$), harmonic analysis such as Poisson formula seems compromised.

Is it possible to derive a functional equation similar to the classical one for regular $\theta$? Or maybe in a direct manner get some decay bounds ?

Note: in the case of primitive sublattice one can relate the $\theta^{(r)}_\Lambda$ series with $\theta^{\textrm{rk}(\Lambda)-r}_{\Lambda^\lor}$ by relating a rank $r$ primitive sub-lattice $\ell\subset\Lambda$ with a sub-lattice of corank $r$ in $\Lambda^\lor$ of determinant $\det(\Lambda)\cdot\det(\ell)$

Comment: Where does this sum over sub-lattices come from and would be useful for ? In the proof of the functional for the Dedekind zeta function there is a sum over sub-lattices that are also $\Lambda$-modules (ideals). In general you can take a matrix $B$ such that $B\Lambda$ is a ring.

Comment: Directly from geometry-of-numbers considerations (looking at this kind of generalisation to study the behaviour of sublattices seems quite natural when you see how much information  the usual theta series carries). The problem with the proof for the Dedekind zeta is that it somewhat "forgots" the Z-modules that are not ideals.

Comment: You should explain more concretely where it comes from and what it is useful for, it would help seing how you'd accept to modify it.

Comment: Would something like the Siegel modular theta series be what you're interested in? Or Eisenstein series for $GL(n)$ attached to maximal proper parabolics stabilizing $r$-dimensional subspaces (with no cuspidal data, so in that regard "degenerate")? Poisson summation (together with a lemma of Bochner) still does prove the functional equations for the _minimal_ parabolic Eisenstein series, and all the (completely) degenerate Eisenstein series are (multi-) residues of that one (see the appendix in Langlands SLN 544).

Comment: @reuns: I want to study the relative mass of sublattices of determinant $>cste$. To do so I wanted to relate the whole sum $\theta^{(r)}$
 with the partial one for sublattices of determinant greater than cste. An exponential decay bound in $\tau$ for either $\theta^{(r)}$ or the partial sum would be sufficient for my purpose (basically it is the same approach than the one of Banaszczyk in his transference paper of '93)

Comment: @paulgarrett: It's not really a Siegel theta here, since I don't have the impression that one the one hand I can express the determinant of my sublattices as traces with elements of the Siegel half-plane and on the other that I can avoid summing on sets of $r$ vectors that are not spanning a rank $r$ sublattice. I'll have a look on Langlands' book, it might be indeed interesting.